# SSRS error adding shared dataset

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

When I add the following code into my report stored procedure, I cannot add the shared dataset to my SSRS report, and it gives me this error:

[image]

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

The code I have added (to a previously working procedure) is:

```
set @sqlstring = Concat(N'INSERT INTO #TEXT_SEARCH_RESULT',
        N'(Result_Name,Count_of_tickets,HT,Created_Group)',
        N' SELECT ',@TimeDefinition,' as RESULT_NAME',
        N' ,sum(COUNT_OF_TICKETS) as COUNT_OF_TICKETS',
        N' ,sum(HT) as HT',
        N' ,''Group'' as CREATED_GROUP',
        N' from #TEXT_SEARCH_MAIN ct',
        N' where (1=1) ')
--other items that append to the string, but have no bearing on the question
set @sqlstring=concat(@sqlstring,N' group by ',@TimeDefinition)
```

The sql statement appends data to an temporary table with data already in it from the previous statement.
@TimeDefinition is declared as `NVARCHAR(100)`
Replacing @TimeDefinition  with the text that is in the variable (example `cast(CREATEDDATE as date`) allows the report to be added
if I remove the `AS` from the concatenated string, then the error simply changes to **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'by'**.
Running the query in SSMS does not give an error

Comment: I'm running from memory here, but I believe the issue is that SSRS isn't able to determine the column values without a value. When you refresh the column values you should be presented with a popup asking for parameter values; are you filling it in? Apologies that I can't check right now, I don't have a running version of SSRS at home, but happy to post a more complete answer tomorrow if this is still outstanding.

Comment: You may want to write this as `[@TimeDefinition]`.  Add the square brackets to the strings prior and after.

Comment: @Zorkolot, that would leave me with a field named `[cast(CREATEDDATE as date)]`

Comment: @SeanC Sorry, I should read more carefully.  The only other thing I see is the CREATED_GROUP is not in the Group By, which is usually where the non-aggregate columns go.

Comment: @Larnu, yes, that was the issue. If you want to add it as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that SSRS wasn't able to determine the columns of the query without a parameter being supplied. When using dynamic SQL, sometimes the dynamic SQL won't have a value if no value is supplied for one (or more) parameters; thus the column values can't be determined. Take a simple example like:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@Col1) + N' AS Result1,' + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'       ' + QUOTENAME(@Col2) + N' AS Result2' + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'FROM MyTable;';
PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Unless values for `@Col1` and `@Col2` are supplied, then the value of `@SQL` will result in *`NULL`*.

When using queries such as these, SSRS will therefore present you with a dialogue window. This'll look something like the below (taken from SSDT 2017)
[image]

You'll need to enter some values into this dialogue (in the second column, which is named `Parameter Value`) so that SSRS can correctly determine the column definitions. Once you've done that, SSRS will create the dataset correctly.

On a related note, I suggest against the use of `1=1`. This just adds time to the processing (as the data engine still needs to check if `1=1`) and can cause the query analyser to make poor choices. It actually can be considered quite bad practice to put things like that in your query's `WHERE` clause.